# Googlebot not executing javascript while internet says otherwise

Tags: javascript, search, cookies, google-search, googlebot

I have a website.

And I am using javascript in one of the pages. That page has

```
  $(document).ready(function(){window.open("URL");$.cookie("location","NYC")});
```

I am testing my page whether the `Googlebot` is running my javascript by using Google's `Webmaster tools` `Fetch as Google`

I just found out my javascript is not executing.

On the internet I have read that google executes `javascript` and also read `cookies` but why I am getting results that `Googlebot` not executing `javascript`?

Comment: maybe info at that link is obsolete but I don't think so... https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more `This is an important idea: the browser can execute JavaScript and produce content on the fly - the crawler cannot.`

Comment: where have you read that google bot executes javascript?